# How to update python selenium download directory

Tags: python, selenium, web, browser, automation

I need some help :) Is there a way to update python selenium chrome browser for its download directory? I am iterating over a list of strings then I wanted to change the download directory of the selenium chrome browser for every word.

Initially this is how to set the default download path but is there a way to update it overtime?

[image]

I tried doing this but it seems it doesn't update, it just doesn't work :( Can someone help me out maybe you know the answer to this. Thank you so much!
[image]

Comment: which OS are you using? I think the issue is related to the directory separator you're using. Try `/` instead of `\ `, or even better, use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

Comment: you can only set the download directory during the driver initialization. If you want to use different directories, then you'll need different instances of the webdriver

Comment: why complicating, just add prefix or suffix to terms, and later develop other script to cut/paste words in desired directories